# Alternative to an entity related to many other entities but only to one at the same time

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm storing other APIs' entities in my database, and using a central local entity related to them as a way to organize them (I need them to have a local ID but also be able to cache some of their information and request any extra information to their respective API if needed).

I was thinking about using the following design but my boss says this wouldn't be good because the central table would have a lot of information (overloaded).

[Class Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WiBm.png)

The resulting table for my central entity would be:

[Central Table Fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbMY0.png)

Only one FK would have a value for every row, and the remaining would be null.
I don't know if I could use some design pattern or any other alternative to do this.

Comment: What if you had 26 more entity types to deal with? (In short, can you think of a solution that uses just 1 external entity id column?)

Comment: All the tables in the diagram are local. The tables on the right have a column for their external entity id. The problem is not on the tables on the right, it's on the table on the left. Because if I had 26 more entity types, I'd have 26 more columns in it (as foreign keys) creating a massive and somewhat disorganized table.